# Wordpress search seems to look into permalink (which is bad)

Tags: permalinks, search

It looks like when you search for the domain name in the wordpress search box, you get all your content listed because the domain name is in each permalink.
I've tried many things, but it seems to be "harcoded".
Is it normal ?
How can I get this work 'normally' ?

thx for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we try searching for *example.tld*, then the default search query looks into the post *title* and *content* with:

```
  ... (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%example.tld%') 
OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%example.tld%') ...
```

When we add an attachment or a local link, into the post content, we normally get the full url, for example:

```
http://example.tld/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/image.jpg
```

so I would think that you're just picking up those in your search.

Try for example to create a post with the title *Test* but without any post content and see if it shows up in your search results.

Comment: you're so right... I've looked into the code eventually, as you did, and ended to the conclusion.
Thx for pointing this out !